# Вывести повторяющиеся значения списка (вопрос по конкретному методу решения)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while

Чуть больше месяца изучаю Python, по учебникам, youtube и онлайн-урокам. Мой вопрос по задаче, решение которой я видел (возможно, один и тот же курс). Но там она решена другими способами. В данном случае хотел бы узнать что не так с моим решением. По ощущениям, логика решения верна, но надо убрать одну ошибку.

**Условие:** напишите программу, которая принимает на вход список чисел в одной строке и выводит на экран в одну строку значения, которые встречаются в нём более одного раза. Выводимые числа не должны повторяться, порядок их вывода может быть произвольным. Например, если на входе дано: 4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3, на выходе должно быть: 0 3 4.

Мое решение:

```
a = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
a.sort()                               # сортировка
b = []                                 # новый пустой список

for i in range(len(a) - 1):

    if a[i] == a[i + 1] % len(a):      # если равны два соседних члена списка...
        b.append(a[i])                 # первый из них переносим в новый список.
        while a[i] == a[i + 1]:        # и удаляем одинаковые значения чтобы не было повтора
            a.pop(a[i])

    else:
        continue
print(*b, end=' ')
```

Итак, главная загвоздка - вывести повторяющиеся значения **один** раз. Т.е. после переноса a[i] в новый список другие равные ему числа удаляются до тех пор, пока к сравнению не будет подано новое число. Часть кода `a[i + 1] % len(a)` оформил таким образом, чтобы остановить цикл на предпоследнем члене списка (нашел способ в разборе чужого решения). Для этого же выше применял  `range(len(a) - 1)`. Тем не менее, для строки с while регулярно выводится ошибка 'IndexError: list index out of range'.
Знаю, что можно решить ее в две строчки, может даже в одну. Но сейчас мне важнее на примере этого решения найти изъян в собственной логике.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я могу предложить вам немного другой способ решения:

```
a = [int(j) for j in input().split()]    #создаём 2 списка
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        if a[i] == a[j] and a[i] not in b:
            b.append(a[i])    

print(*b)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Жалею, что сам не додумался сравнить новый список с изначальным, это так логично и в общем-то очевидно. Но, буду анализировать! :-)

Comment: Удачи в изучении, мой друг. И я буду рад если вы проголосуйте "ЗА" моё решение

Comment: Пересмотрел решение в пайчарме. Получается немного не то - `print(b)` выводит то, что должно было быть убрано. Т.е. для примера - на входе `4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3`, на выходе не `0 3 4`, а `4 8 0 3 2`. Фактически, мы удаляем дубли. P.S. Собственно, эту задачу вы похоже и решили, в том смысле что возможно она не очевидно сформулирована (?). Т.е. надо вывести числа, **которые повторяются более одного раза**, без дублей (а не просто без дублей).

Comment: Исправлено, проверяй

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
 a[i + 1] % len(a)
```

не имеет смысла. Вы понимаете, что там могло делаться?  Вот что:

```
a[(i + 1) % len(a)]
```

но вам это всё равно не нужно, т.е. диапазон ограничен

Вы меняете список, по которому итерируетесь, так делать нельзя.

И здесь запросто выходите за границу списка, если удалили весь хвост.

```
while a[i] == a[i + 1]:
        a.pop(a[i])
```

А

```
else:
    continue
```

просто не нужно.

Давайте сделаем так - будем проверять левый и правый элементы, таким образом из длинной серии условие сработает только на последней паре. И предусмотрим аккуратную проверку для последнего элемента. И удалять ничего не надо. (Можно превратить в однострочник, но незачем)

```
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[i - 1] and (i + 1 == len(a) or a[i] != a[i + 1]):
        print(a[i], end=' ')
```

Добавлю линейный алгоритм

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter([4, 8, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0, 3])
for k in c:
    if c[k]>1:
        print(k)
```

или однострочником

```
print(" ".join(str(k) for k, v in Counter([4, 8, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0, 3]).items() if v > 1))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сколько комбинаций я перебрал, и такое ощущение словно обходил ваше решение. Правильно, с `a[(i + 1) % len(a)]` вы верно написали про скобки.  И да, чутье подсказывало что тут что-то не так - "Вы меняете список, по которому итерируетесь, так делать нельзя."

Comment: Хм... Я разобрал ваши ошибки, привёл приличные методы решения, а в качестве ответа вы принимаете   лабуду с чуть ли не кубической сложностью?

Comment: Я благодарен вам за помощь и участие.

Comment: Это мой первый вопрос (и первый день на сайте), поэтому я искренне не знаю что значат эти рейтинги. Часть ваших замечаний я сохранил себе в записи, т.к. на самом деле было ощущение, что читая их я стал уже в процессе переосмысливать некоторые вещи. По поводу кода - я пока на том уровне, когда сложно сравнивать несколько решений. В данном случае человек попросил поставить галочку - я не отказал. Если бы было технически возможно - отблагодарил бы всех кто ответил за сам факт уделенного времени. Еще раз спасибо за помощь, и надеюсь что вы не в обиде!

Answer (score 1):

При больших значениях `a` этот вариант может быть быстрее Counter

```
import random

a = [random.randint(-10000000, 10000000) for _ in range(5000000)]
s, b = set(), set()
for n in a:
    (b if n in s else s).add(n)
print(*b)
```

Comment: Да, вполне возможно

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. Был бы благодарен, если бы вы рассказали как. Поскольку такой код еще вне области моих знаний.